# AWS API Gateway Generated SDK does not contain client js file

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have created an API using the AWS Api Gateway Service, and am ready to use the javascript sdk in a simple webpage.

However, the instructions for using the javascript SDK [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-javascript.html) show an import for a js file called apigClient. I can only assume this is where the client class is stored for the api. However, when I generate the SDK for MY API, there is no such file (as in, the older file in the unzipped folder is lib. There is no js file in the root directory.)

Am I expected to create this file on my own? If so, I did not see any instructions to do so. Are there? What am I missing here?

Comment: This file *should* be created for you. Have you created necessary models for requests and responses in your API?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it by **deploying API**.

See step4 "Deploy Your API" in this link.

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/module-4/